# Connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse from Azure Databricks Notebook

Tags: azure, databricks

Using [this link][1] to setup my Databricks notebook to connect to Azure SQL. I'm trying to run a SQL query in the notebook.  But getting the error

```
   at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.Utils$.wrapExceptions(Utils.scala:258)
    at
    at linea51bced512544f18bbe612d4c624fde241.$read.<init>(command-3691084376529925:86)
    at linea51bced512544f18bbe612d4c624fde241.$read$.<init>(command-3691084376529925:90)
    at linea51bced512544f18bbe612d4c624fde241.$read$.<clinit>(command-3691084376529925)
    at linea51bced512544f18bbe612d4c624fde241.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at linea51bced512544f18bbe612d4c624fde241.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at linea51bced512544f18bbe612d4c624fde241.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

after entering the following:

```
%scala 

Class.forName("com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}

spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<your-storage-account-access-key>")

    // Load data from a SQL DW query
   val df: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx.database.windows.net:1433")
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://xxxxx@xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/https:")
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("query", "select * from xxxx.xxxx")
  .load()


  [1]: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html#
```

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @Sai added it. thanks

Comment: jKraut Is the query you were passing just the "select * from db.table"? or was it a complex one? If you are indeed selecting the whole table, could you try: `.option("dbTable", "my_table_in_dw")` instead?

Comment: You see the bit that says '<your-storage-account-name>' and '<your-storage-account-access-key>' are they the actual values from the script or have you put them there as an attempt to hide the real values?

Comment: @wBob - in attempt to hide the creditials